# Python Bisection Number Guessing Game

Tags: python, bisection

I am trying to write a simple bisection method question and it works perfectly fine as long as I don't have a certain conditional statement which I have commented out. What is the reason for this? This is not a homework question.

```
low = 0 
high = 100 
ans = (low+high)/2 
print "Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
print "Is your secret number " + str(ans) + "?"
response = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ") 
response = str(response)
while response != "c": 
   if response == "h":
        high = ans 
        ans = (low + high)/2 
        print "Is your secret number " + str(ans) + "?"
        response = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")  
        response = str(response) 

   if response == "l": 
        low = ans 
        ans = (low + high)/2 
        print "Is your secret number " + str(ans) + "?"
        response = raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly. ")  
        response = str(response)

   if response == "c" :
        break

  # if response != "c" or response != "h" or response != "l":
   #     response = raw_input("Please enter a 'h', 'l', or 'c' ")
    #    response = str(response)

print "Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(ans)
```

Is this because the while loop has the same condition as the while loop? If so what is the best way to change this?

Comment: Just a tip. Use `if... elif... else...` instead of `if...; if...; if...;` when you're checking conditions for the same variable. It is less prone to bugs and is faster because you eliminate unnecessary comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That condition will always be true because you are comparing for inequality with multiple things. It would be like asking "If this character isn't `c`, **or** if it isn't `h`, **or** if it isn't `l`, *do this*. It can't be three things at once, so it will always evaluate as true.

Instead, you should use `if response not in ['c','h','l']`, which is basically like replacing **or** with **and** in the sentence above. Or even better in your case, just use an `else` statement because your existing conditions already ensure what you are trying to check for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a double while loop :

```
while True:
    response = None
    print "Is your secret number " + str(ans) + "?"
    response = str(raw_input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly."))

    while response not in ['h', 'c', 'l']:
        response = str(raw_input("Please enter a 'h', 'l', or 'c' "))

    if response == 'c':
         break

    if response == 'l':
        low = ans 
    else:
        high = ans 
    ans = (low + high)/2
```

Comment: Line 3 is wrong. It should be print( "Is your secret number" + str(guess) + "?") not as you wrote it